# Variance Covariance for logit with elastic net

Tags: logistic, variance, elastic-net

How do you calculate an estimate for the variance covariance matrix of a logistic regression with elastic net regularization?

Starting from the variance-covariance matrix of a plain vanilla logistic regression, how does the formula need to be augmented:
$\hat{\Sigma}=-\left[\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})XX^{T}\right]^{-1}$
where $\hat{p}=\frac{1}{1+exp(X^{T}\hat{\Theta})}$
If you don't know the answer for elastic net, how would this be implemented for a logistic regression with ridge regularization?

Update: This [link](http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/764-F11/notes/9-1.pdf) suggests OLS ridge is:
M = $(X'X+λI)^{−1}X'$
var(β)= ${\sigma}^{2}MM'$

Comment: I always thought there wasn't an analytical solution the covariance matrix in regularized regression and that standard errors need to be bootstrapped. No regularized regression routine I know of produces standard errors. I'd very much like to be wrong.

Comment: Maybe, but I thought I'd read somewhere that there is a solution. A cursory search reveals this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106254/variance-covariance-matrix-for-ridge-regression-with-stochastic-lambda

Comment: I'm tempted to put a bounty on that question for a real answer. Or maybe Community Wiki would be more appropriate? I'm not sure.

Comment: There's also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660120/variance-inflation-factor-in-ridge-regression-in-python

Comment: In general there's no closed-form expression for the coefficients in the logistic regression model, but [this paper](http://czep.net/stat/mlelr.pdf) provides an equation for the variance-covariance matrix associated with a particular beta value in equation (16). This could get you started on deriving the updated variance-covariance matrix for a particular regularization term.

Comment: @josilber. Thanks, equation (16) is just the information matrix, which is the equation that I am using above. Maybe all I need to do is calculate the hessian with ridge terms added in to the optimization problem. I imagine that all lasso shrunken terms should just be set to NA.

Comment: @josilber Are you confident about this? I've been trying to find a link on ridge regressions and logit or glm and can't find anything.

Comment: I think there is no closed-form equation for the variance-covariance matrix of an elastic net regularised GLM, but numerically it could be calculated either via (1) bootstrapping, (2) using the delta method, from the gradient of the coefficients with respect to the data or (3) by solving the Hessian matrix. For ridge penalized GLMs there is I think, as then one can just use the equivalent formula than the one you mentioned for weighted least squares, and use the weights obtained in the last step of the IRLS algorithm (I think, W in the IRLS algo mentioned in https://bwlewis.github.io/GLM/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [this paper](http://czep.net/stat/mlelr.pdf), Eq. (12), the $(i, j)$ element of the variance-covariance matrix for logistic regression is $\frac{\partial^2l(\hat\beta)}{\partial\hat\beta_i\partial\hat\beta_j}$, where $l(\hat\beta)$ is the log-conditional likelihood of coefficients $\hat\beta$ given the observed data.

As stated in [this paper](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/articulo/1992-JSTOR-Cessie-Logistic_Regression.pdf), Eq. 2.1, the log-conditional likelihood for ridge-regularized logistic regression with parameter $\lambda$ is defined as $l^\lambda(\hat\beta) := l(\hat\beta) - \lambda\hat\beta'\hat\beta$.

Hence, if we define $V(\hat\beta)$ to be the variance-covariance matrix of non-regularized logistic regression, then the variance-covariance matrix of ridge-regularized logistic regression is $V^\lambda(\hat\beta) = V(\hat\beta) - 2\lambda I$.

Comment: Bravo! Worth pointing out that the second paper states that "Unfortunately, this approximation to the variance... cannot be used directly to construct approximate confidence intervals around beta, since we have to take into account the bias of the estimate. Jackknife and bootstrapping might be possible methods to obtain more insight into the variability of beta". Kind of defeats the whole point for me.