# Variance-Covariance Matrix for $l_1$ regularized binomial logistic regression

Tags: logistic, references, inference, lasso, regularization

Given design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ and response vector $y \in \{ 0,1 \}^n$, I want to find the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients $\hat{\beta}$ from an $l_1$-regularized logistic regression with regularization parameter $\lambda > 0$.

If I understand correctly, there is no closed-form solution for this as the penalized log-likelihood function $l(\beta \vert X, y, \lambda)$ is not differentiable. Approximations have been proposed in Tibshirani ([1996](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/lasso.pdf)), and Li and Fan ([2001](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~rli/research/penlike.pdf)), but these only apply to the non-zero coefficients in $\hat{\beta}$. Bootstrap and Bayesian lasso ([2010](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/archived/casella/Papers/BL-Final.pdf)) are other methods to compute standard errors, but I think they would be too computationally intensive for my purposes. There is a question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106275/variance-covariance-for-logit-with-elastic-net) with an answer that only applies to $l_2$-regularized logistic regression.

Are there any other fast and accurate alternatives for variance-covariance matrix computation of the coefficients in *frequentist* lasso logistic regression?

Answer (score 2):

(This answer is more of a comment than a full answer, but I'm posting it here since I don't have enough rep to comment.)

This is a *very* hard question to give an good answer to. Even in the non-penalized case, the covariance estimate for the parameters is based on a normal approximation. When you start penalizing, you also enter the realm of "post-selection inference" which is an active area of research. The work on post-selection inference for GLMs (including logistic regression) is in its infancy, but see [1] for a recent reference on it. I believe the method described in this paper is implemented in the `selectiveInference` `R` package [2].

Even ignoring the mathematical difficulty, there are *philosophical* difficulties inherent in your question. Covariance matrices of estimators are tied to coverage under repeated sampling in the frequentist framework. If you had a new sample, you're not guaranteed to select the same variables, so can we even define "coverage" in a sensible way? There are many different (valid) ways to define coverage, each of which gives rise to a different school of thought about how post-selection inference should be defined and performed.

[1] J. Taylor, R. Tibshirani. "Post-selection inference for L1-penalized likelihood models." Canadian Journal of Statistics (to appear). 
http://doi.org/10.1002/cjs.11313

[2] https://cran.r-project.org/package=selectiveInference